# Service (uses service factory) to return objects of different types

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I need to create a service, which uses another factory service, and return objects of different types.
Here's a definitions of my services:

```
services:
    games.search_factory:
        class: %games.search_factory.class%
        calls:
           - [ setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]

    games.search:
        class: %games.search.base.class%
        factory_service: games.search_factory
        factory_method: get
```

My `%games.search_factory.class%` *get* method returns different objects depending on the request parameters.
My `%games.search.base.class%` is abstract.
My goal is - when I call

```
$this->get("games.search");
```

I want to get the result of factory method. But when I run the code, I get an error: **FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class**.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does DI system try to instantiate my class, instead of returning the result of my factory method?
2. Is there a way to implement what I need (nicely and concisely)?

**Update:** I had a bug in the part of code, which is not shown here. Besides these two services for search, I had a service for each search type, and returned these services from a factory. But in the definition of these services, I've used my base class (which is abstract) as a class.

So nice conclusion is that ***it is possible to return an objects of different types from a factory.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

> When you specify the class to use for the factory (via factory_class) 
>       the method will be called statically. 
>       If the factory itself should be instantiated and the resulting object's method called 
>       (as in this example), configure the factory itself as a service

In order to inject the container into your factory you will either need to make the factory instantionable (not abstract) or pass the container as an argument to the static get method.  I'm not aware of any way to declare a service as being static.

Comment: But my factory *is* instantionable. And I did exactly what doc says: i've configured my factory as a separate service so it could take a container parameter. The problem is that when I use this factory to get instances for my games.search service, I get not the result of factory's get method, but a new instance of %games.search.base.class%, which is at lease wierd for me

Comment: Ok. Start debugging by putting die statements in your factory constructor and in factory.get.  I'm guessing that your factory is not properly reading the route parameters and as a result is returning a default class.  If the die's are getting called then please post your factory code.

Comment: Thanks, your advice really helped ! I've found a bug in the code. The idea was to return services from my factory (each search is a service). But in a definition of each service, i've just copy-pasted the base class as each services class (and this class is abstract)

Comment: Just a suggestion: you might want to see if you can replace the container with specific services such as request.  Injecting the container is often overkill for these sorts of things.